# Multiple IC identification (IR321M, CU257, 33C86W6, P602-38N, 17AHK7K, Si3007-FS, A2737, 508X, CAT7551CB)

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image: IC components]

These are a few ICs I scavenged from old PC graphic cards, audio cards and lan cards.
Can't find any datasheet for them.

Markings:

- The Si3007-FS is made by Silicon labs.
  Markings : Si3007-FS 0739BG FA8Q
- International rectifier. Markings : 321M 6F2D F809AV
- ST markings: 33C86W6 9735F
- P602-38N SCL A0 ATP88
- TI at bottom right, markings: 17AHK7K F02
- TI at right middle row, markings : CU257 36M CXDT
- the IC at upper right corner, Markings: [LOGO] CAT7551CB XC11CZ9

Logo identification is also helpful.

Comment: Not quite sure how to answer this, as it contains multiple chips to be identified. As I've seen other questions where an answer contains multiple answers, it was noted to separate things to make voting on single parts possible, so I'll go with that.

Comment: Very elusive: Si3007, only found a mention in [AN72](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/application-notes/an72.pdf), something with telephones?

Comment: Also horrible to search: 508X, found a lot of measurements 5.08 x 2.10 or 508 x 300 :-/ And the ST chip is also really hard to find, somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

P602-38N SCL A0 ATP88

---

Phaselink PLL602-38NSCL: [datasheet](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/133652/PLL/PLL602-38NSCL.html), a 4x Low Phase Noise Multiplier PECL XO

Phaselink was bought by Micrel in [2012](https://www.eetimes.com/micrel-to-acquire-controlling-stake-in-phaselink/) which was bought by Microchip in [2015](https://www.microchip.com/announcements/microchip-announces-the-acquisition-of-micrel/38).

Comment: Thanks. Where I live accessing to many datasheet websites is banned. My search results are limited. Thanks for your links and help.

Comment: @Elementronics so you can't access the datasheet I linked here? That's a bummer.

Comment: @Through VPNs I can see them.

Answer (score 3):

TI Chips: [very helpful search](https://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/partlookup.tsp#divline)

- TI at right middle row, markings : CU257 36M CXDT: [SN74CBT3257](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74CBT3257)
- TI at bottom right, markings: 17AHK7K F02: probably [SN74F02](https://www.ti.com/product/SN74F02)

Answer (score 2):

International rectifier. Markings : 321M 6F2D F809AV

---

Based on:

[image: SOIC8 IRF Marking]

(taken from [this](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/546733/IRF/IRF8113.html) datasheet)

This would make:

321M -> Year 3 Weak 21 assembled in M

Lot Code: 6F2D

Part number: F809AV. But I can't find information about F809AV anywhere.

International rectifier is now part of Infineon (since 2014).

Answer (score 1):

the IC at upper right corner, Markings: [LOGO] CAT7551CB XC11CZ9:

---

Catalyst Semiconductor bought by ON Semi in 2009 made chips starting with CAT. No datasheet to be found. But the logo doesn't match, so could be a wrong lead there.